# Function encryption AES-256-CBC, search mysql

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I work with PHP and MySQL, and enter data in encrypted form using this function in PHP:

```
function encrypt_decrypt($action, $string) {
    $output = false;

    $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
    $secret_key = 'This is my secret key';
    $secret_iv = 'This is my secret iv';

    // hash
    $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);

    // iv - encrypt method AES-256-CBC expects 16 bytes - else you will get a warning
    $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);

    if( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
        $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
        $output = base64_encode($output);
    }
    else if( $action == 'decrypt' ){
        $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
    }

    return $output;
}
```

And I ended up running into a huge problem.

I need to search the table, and need to use the MySQL `LIKE` function.

**How can I do this?**

I looked for documentation and found that MySQL has the AES encryption, but I'm completely lost.

This function written in PHP MySQL exists, or is to make it work?

Comment: So you want to perform a `LIKE` match on the plaintext?

Comment: @Halcyon Yes, style `SELECT * FROM `comments` WHERE `id` LIKE '%A-E-S%'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you enter ciphertext into MySQL, that

- has been encrypted outside of MySQL
- does not preserve likeness (as most encryptions don't)

you can't perform a `LIKE` search on it.

If you move encryption into the database, you can perform `LIKE` searches, but be prepared to take a heavy computational performance hit: Basically MySQL has to decrypt the complete column in addition to the cost involved with the `LIKE` itself.

The best option is to search for some redesign options, that allow you to simply not do that.